# Error when querying HyperLedger Fabric Blockchain - "Could not get deployment transaction for chaincode"

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have setup 4 peers with the help of the Fabric Network Setup guide. I managed to deploy a CC then call the invoke function using the REST API calls.

While both the messages resulted in a success the query message simply fails. This is weird as it works fine when the same set of commands are applied to a single peer instantiated in dev mode (peer node start --peer-chaincodedev).

Note that the 4 nodes are setup using Docker containers. Here is an example of what the JSON response for query looks like:

```
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"error":{
"code":-32003,
"message":"Query failure",
"data":"Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for 04233c6dd8364b9f0749882eb6d1b50992b942aa0a664182946f411ab46802a88574932ccd75f8c75e780036e363d52dd56ccadc2bfde95709fc39148d76f050 - LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found)"
},
"id":5
}
```

When I performed a GET call to retrieve data for a transaction based on the hash retrieved after the invoke call the response says it couldn't find the specified transaction.

Viewing the data in the blocks yields a block which I believe has no data in it - meaning the deploy transaction simply failed.

**EDIT**: 
The following is the params passed via JSON for deployment at the URL http://172.17.0.2:7050/chaincode (POST)

```
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"method":"deploy",
"params":{
"type":1,
"chaincodeID":{
"path":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"
},
"ctorMsg":{
"function":"init",
"args":[
"a",
"100",
"b",
"200"
]
}
},
"id":1
}
```

Comment: could you please show the command you are using for deployment ?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori 
The following is the the command I am passing using REST at the url: http://172.17.0.2:7050/chaincode (POST)

{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "path":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"

    },
    "ctorMsg": {
        "function":"init",
        "args":["a", "100", "b", "200"]
    }
  },
  "id": 1
}

Comment: this seems ok. could you please tell us which version of fabric are you using

Comment: @SufiyanGhori
I managed to start the peers using a docker-compose files on the Github repo of a user by the name Yeasy. I used to instantiate 4 peers in 4 terminals with arguments passed, with the docker-compose up method  the peers started flawlessly and the chaincode deploy/invoke/query worked fine.

Link: https://github.com/yeasy/docker-compose-files/tree/master/hyperledger/pbft

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at logging when you deploy your chaincode, if you see a message `Error building images: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage.`  then I guess your problem is the docker image hyperledger/fabric-baseimage missing.

to solve the proble, just pull the hyperledger/fabric-baseimage image and tag as latest

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.2.2
docker tag <image_id> hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:latest
```

Basically, when you deploy the chaincode, the peer node requests to docker host to run the fabric-baseimage to run the chaincode. you can `docker ps` and you will see `dev-node_name-04233c6dd8364b9f0749882eb6d1b50992b942aa0a664182946f411ab46802a88574932ccd75f8c75e780036e363d52dd56ccadc2bfde95709fc39148d76f050` is running if you can deploy the chaincode successfully.